# Questions about SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I'm trying to prevent sql injection. My code is as follows

```
$stmt = $db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name,user_password_hash,user_email,user_firstname,user_lastname,user_registerip,user_lastip,user_created,user_rank,user_block) VALUES (:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_firstname, :user_lastname, :user_registerip, :user_lastip, :user_created, :user_rank, :user_block)");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $txtName);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_password_hash', $txtPassword);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_email', $txtMail);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_firstname', $txtFirst);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_lastname', $txtLast);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_registerip', $txtRIP);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_lastip', $txtIP);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_created', $txtCreated);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_rank', $txtRank);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_block', $txtBlock);
$stmt->execute();
```

But I don't know what to do with a line like this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':user_block', $txtBlock);
```

Where do I define those variables such as `$txtBlock` and how do I connect my `input` names to the PHP code?

Comment: You have already defined variable to your query! Are you getting any error?

Comment: @RonakPatel Hi Ronak, somebody followed up on the issue below and it's solved now, but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define those variables to be what you like. If you are using a form like:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input name="example" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then on the page `process.php`, you can access all of the variables through the `$_POST` global. So to get the data from the field `example`, and assign it to `$txtBlock`, you can do:

```
$txtBlock = $_POST["example"];
```

In terms of SQL injection, you have prepared your query and bound variables to it already. There is no need to worry about sanitising inputs further. I find the [following resource](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) helpful when talking about PDO.

Comment: Ah. So it's like that. Alright, you helped me a step further with this. Thanks. I was a little confused because people are so extremely careful with these scripts that I didn't knew what to do.